Sequence with diagonal lines and circles
This is from an online demo preparing for a job recruitment. https://werkenvoor.be/nl/solliciteren/selectietesten/testinhoud/test-abstract-redeneervermogen

The question is which figure is next? Why is it the first one?

I don't know if this is the pattern that the question setters had in mind, but it seems to work.
There are 5 columns, each with a top and a bottom figure.
If you look at

 the difference between the top figures of the second and third column, a square is removed and a circle added, so the difference matches the circle and square figure at the bottom of column one. Similarly, the difference between the bottom figures of the second and third columns matches the top figure of column one. In short, the difference of columns 2 and 3 is equal to column 1 with its figures swapped.

 The same is true for the next columns. The difference of columns 3 and 4 is equal to column 2 with its figures swapped.

 To continue that pattern, the column 5 must be equal to the figures given in the first option.

